# Redirect an user on database update

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Another beginner question here :/...

I have a MySQL database and a web application with some PHP files, let say page1.php and page2.php.

When an user is on page1.php, I need him to be redirected automatically to page2.php when my database gets a specific update. Let table "foo" be:

```
-------------------
| ID | NAME | AGE |
-------------------
| 1  | Bob  | 32  |
-------------------
| 2  | Ken  | 28  |
-------------------
```

If database is updated and Ken's age become let's say 30, I'd like the user on page1.php to get redirected on page2.php.

I know that this can be achieved trough some AJAX by constantly calling a php file with setInterval() method but I couldn't find anything to handle a redirect function. All I found so far are scripts that would update a div container in an HTML page like:

```
<script>
setInterval(
(function () {
$("#somediv").load("file.php");
}), 10000);
</script>
<div id="somediv"></div>
```

which obviously wouldn't help me in redirecting an user. I've been on this for hours now and trust me guys I did a lot of research. So what would be the best method to write a script that automatically looks for a specified data to be inserted into a MySQL database, then redirect the user from page1.php to page2.php?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: No need to watch with database update.Better pass the redirect the first  ajax call success.like `$("#somediv").load("file.php",function(){ //do with redirection })`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the right idea with an AJAX call, but rather than using `$.load()`, use something like `$.get()`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function check_db() {
        $.get( 'file.php', function( result ) {
            if ( result == 'changed' ) {
                location.href = 'page2.php';
            }

            setTimeout( 'check_db', 10000 );
        } );
    }

    check_db();
</script>
```

Then have `file.php` output "changed" if the database change you're looking for has occurred.

The above JavaScript will call `file.php` every 10 seconds, which will check for the database change.  If it occurred, then it would output "change", and the `location.href` method will use JS to redirect you to `page2.php`.

@vher2 made a good point about `file.php` perhaps taking too long to return.  I've modified the example to take that into account.  So rather than the calling running every 10 seconds, it will not run with 10 seconds in between the end of one call and the beginning of the next.

Comment: `setInterval` will run every 10 seconds. What if a call to `file.php` takes longer, more than 10 seconds. The next run will call again `file.php` now there's two call and so on. You should use `$.ajax`, `complete` callback instead.

Comment: That's a good point. I hadn't considered that it might take a while to run. I'm not sure how using the `complete` callback would handle this though, but I have implemented a solution using another method and updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you very much @Nick Coons I'll look further into this it's getting late here I'll try it tomorrow but thanks again it looks pretty much what I need :)

Comment: And I tried to upvote your answer but I'm still missing a darn 4 reputation haha

Comment: @DjShoucrout Not anymore, I just upvoted your question. :-)

Comment: It worked like a charm thank you very much @vher2 too :)

Answer (score 0):

You can just simply let your SQL do you thing, check if the sql updated the table and then afterwards do a header location, like so:

```
$query = $DB->query("UPDATE something SET age = '$30' WHERE member_id = '$member_id'");

if($query) {
 header('Location: page2.php');
}
```

Comment: "This" user is not updating the database instead he is there waiting on "page1.php" and if somehow the database is updated he gets redirected to "page2.php".

Comment: Oh, I've misunderstood the question then, sorry. I'd suggest Nick Coons answer then :)

Comment: No problem I should have been more specific in my question thanks for your help tho :)